# Is $(-\infty, \alpha)$ closed in the topological space $\mathbb{R}_k$?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

**BACKGROUND**

Let
$$K := \left\{\frac{1}{n} \mid n \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}\right\} = \left\{\frac{1}{1}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \ldots\right\},$$
where $\mathbb{Z}_{+}$ is the set of all positive integers.

Let
$$\mathscr{B}_k = \left\{(a,b) \subseteq \mathbb{R} \mid a, b \in \mathbb{R}, a < b\right\} \cup \left\{(c,d)-K \mid c, d \in \mathbb{N}, c < d\right\}.$$

Then $\mathscr{B}_k$ is a basis for a topology on $\mathbb{R}$, and this is called the $K$-topology on $\mathbb{R}$ and is denoted as $\mathbb{R}_k$.

Now, a subset $C$ of the topological space $X$ is said to be **closed** if $X - C$ is open.

**QUESTION**

> In the topological space $\mathbb{R}_k$, is $(-\infty, \alpha)$ closed?

**ATTEMPT**

$$(-\infty, \alpha) \text{ closed in } \mathbb{R}_k \iff {\mathbb{R}_k} \setminus (-\infty, \alpha) \text{ open in } \mathbb{R}_k \iff \mathbb{R}_k \setminus (-\infty, \alpha) = \bigcup_{i \in I}{\mathscr{B}_k}$$
Therefore, there exists an $i_0 \in I$ such that
$$\mathbb{R}_k \setminus (-\infty, \alpha) = \mathscr{B}_{k_{i_0}}.$$ 
This is true if and only if $(-\infty, \alpha) \notin \mathscr{B}_{k_{i_0}}$.
But
$$\mathscr{B}_{k_{i_0}} = \left\{(a_0,b_0) \subseteq \mathbb{R} \mid a_0, b_0 \in \mathbb{R}, a_0 < b_0\right\} \cup \left\{(c_0,d_0)-K \mid c_0, d_0 \in \mathbb{N}, c_0 < d_0\right\}.$$

At this point, I am stuck.  I am not sure if what I am doing is even correct.  Any hints that you can provide will be appreciated.

**ADDED August 27 2017**

The existing answers are inadequate, as we have not yet covered limit points (i.e., the derived set) nor connectedness for $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}_k$.

Comment: The question is whether $[\alpha,+\infty)$ is open. Does it contain any neighbourhood of $\alpha$?

Comment: No, because if it does contain (say) an $\epsilon$-neigbourhood of $\alpha$, then $\alpha - (\epsilon/2) \in [\alpha, +\infty)$, contradicting $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: It would be better to ask if $(-\infty,\alpha)\times \{0\}$ is closed in $\mathbb R^k,$ where $0= (0,0,\dots,0)\in \mathbb R^{k-1}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. $(-\infty, \alpha) =: A$ is closed only if $A' \subseteq A$, but $\alpha \in A'$ and $\alpha \notin A$.

Comment: What is $A'$, @MarcelS?

Comment: The derived set = set of all limit points of A. a closed set contains all it's limit points. Alpha is clearly one, but not contained in the interval, hence A cannot be closed

Comment: Is it also true that
$$A' = \text{ closure of } A?$$

Comment: No. The closure contains all limit points, but not every point in the closure must be a limit point. E.g. for the subset of the real line with the usual topology, $B := (0;1) \cup {2}$, we have $closure(B) = [0;1] \cup {2}$, but $B' = [0;1] $

Answer (score 0):

A set $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}_k$ is open if and only if it is the union of open sets. You can express $(-\infty,\alpha)$ as

$$\bigcup_{x<\alpha}(x,\alpha)$$

where every $(x,\alpha)$ is a basis element and thus open.

Comment: a set can be open and closed at the same time though. Knowing that the set is open doesn't help us in determinig whether it is closed.

Comment: I was thinking that $\mathbb{R}$ is connected so it can't have clopen sets, but since the $K$ topology is finer than the usual one connectedness isn't immediate. That's fair.